# SQLite trigger to update a column on editing updates the column for all records in table

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Hypothetical table x, with columns (all of type `text`):

- name
- sname
- sqlmodded

I'd like to create a trigger to set the value of `sqlmodded` to '1' if any column in the record is updated.

My trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER UPDATE
ON x
FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN old.sqlmodded IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE x
       SET sqlmodded = '1';
END;
```

When I run an update statement to change a value of `name` or `sname`, the trigger kicks in but alters `sqlmodded` for all records in the table.

Here's code to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE "x"(
"NAME" Text,
"SNAME" Text,
"sqlmodded" Text );

CREATE TRIGGER "trigger1"
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON "x"
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN old.sqlmodded is null
BEGIN UPDATE x SET sqlmodded = '1'; END;
```

Now insert a few records:

```
INSERT INTO x
    (
      name
    , sname
    ) VALUES
    (
      "Joe"
    , "Bloggs"
    )
    ;

INSERT INTO x
(
  name
, sname
) VALUES
(
  "Joline"
, "Bloggs"
)
;
```

Now run an update:

```
UPDATE x
SET
  name = "Justine"
WHERE name = "Joline"
;
```

If you view the resulting two records both records will have had `sqlmodded` set to 1.

Comment: I've since found that the trigger does indeed get run, but the results were not showing in SQLiteStudio despite refreshing the schema.  Worse though, changing a single record results in all records in the table  having sqlmodded set to '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sqlmods
         AFTER UPDATE
            ON x
      FOR EACH ROW
          WHEN old.sqlmodded IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE x
       SET sqlmodded = TRUE
     WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The trigger runs this command:

```
UPDATE x
   SET sqlmodded = '1';
```

This statement indeed updates all rows in the table. This is how SQL works.

If you want to update only a specific row, you have to tell the database which row that would be:

```
UPDATE x
SET sqlmodded = '1'
WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
```